# Formulate strict constraints in docplex

Tags: python, constraints, mathematical-optimization, docplex

I am trying to model the following strict constraint in python with docplex:

```
mdl.add_constraint(sum(a[i] * mdl.variable[i] for i in range(nrItems)) > b)
```

but I keep getting the error:
docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: Unsupported relational operator: only <=, ==, >= are allowed

How can one programm a strict constraint in docplex?

Comment: >= b + 1 it's all right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small epsilon and turn

```
mdl.add_constraint(sum(a[i] * mdl.variable[i] for i in range(nrItems)) > b)
```

into

```
epsilon=0.00001
mdl.add_constraint(sum(a[i] * mdl.variable[i] for i in range(nrItems)) >= b+epsilon)
```

Answer (score 0):

MIP solvers do not support < and > as these do not make much sense when continuous variables (or relaxations) are involved (both from a mathematical point and from a numerical point of view).